# How to get a string from a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document.

In a cell I have for example this value :

```
CRAZY DOG(1) [FOUR-F33202] 44123
```

I need to get (to put it in other cell) : CRAZY DOG

And I need to get too, in other cell : 44123

Is possible to do it with native functions of Excel ?

Comment: Probably Yes. But you need to provide the rules for the parsing pattern, and with more examples.

Comment: You can use MID function to find last 5 digits (if it's always 5?

you could also use the text-to-columns option breaking on ( the first time and ] the second time, delete the bits you don't need.

Comment: Press F1, type "text functions" and read up.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged only Excel below is an Excel solution.

Cell A1: CRAZY DOG(1) [FOUR-F33202] 44123

Returns "CRAZY DOG":

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1) - 1)
```

Returns "44123":

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("]",A1) - 1)
```